# Delete space between Combobox and label (QGridlayout)

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to create a Application form by PySide, and i follow some tutorial , but i have a problem that is a space between QLabel and QCombobox.

This is my code

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide.QtCore import *

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setMinimumHeight(660)
        self.setMinimumWidth(700)
        self.setMaximumHeight(660)
        self.setMaximumWidth(900)

        grid = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        grid.addWidget(self.First(), 0,0,2,0)

        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.setWindowTitle("Library")
        self.resize(700, 660)

    def First(self):
        groupBox = QtGui.QFrame()
        groupBox.setMaximumWidth(230)
        groupBox.setMaximumHeight(700)

        lbFile = QtGui.QLabel("File :",self)
        lbFolders = QtGui.QLabel("Folders :",self)

        cbFile = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
        cbFile.addItem("File 1")
        cbFile.addItem("File 2")

        lvFolders = QtGui.QListView(self)
        lvFolders.setMaximumWidth(220)
        lvFolders.setMaximumHeight(500)

        vbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(lbFile,0,0)
        vbox.addWidget(cbFile,0,1)
        vbox.addWidget(lbFolders,2,0)
        vbox.addWidget(lvFolders,3,0,1,2)
        groupBox.setLayout(vbox)
        return groupBox


app = QApplication.instance()
if app is None:
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    clock = Window()
    clock.show()
app.exec_()
```

and this is my Form :

[image]

I dont know how to delete the space between QLabel "File" and QCombobox "File 1"

Comment: They are in two separate columns, (spanned by `lvFolders`) that have equal widths. If you want to reduce the space you could e.g. right-align `File:`.

Comment: Or put them both in a QHBoxLayout and add that layout to the cell that the QLabel is currently in.

Comment: You don't really seem to gave a rigid grid there, so you'd probably have easier time if you used nested QHBoxLayouts, possibly inside QVBoxLayout instead of QGridLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the stretch factor for the second column of the layout, and possibly also make the `folders` label span both columns:

```
    vbox = QtGui.QGridLayout()
    vbox.addWidget(lbFile,0,0)
    vbox.addWidget(cbFile,0,1)
    vbox.addWidget(lbFolders,2,0,1,2)
    vbox.addWidget(lvFolders,3,0,1,2)
    vbox.setColumnStretch(1, 1)
```